# StringBuffer: Adding a newline after a certain amount of words for formatting

Tags: java, printing, io, hashmap

Okay so my problem is formatting the output of my program. My program is meant to be a madlib, It reads in a file and then allows the user to enter nouns, adjectives, plurals etc. and then it prints the madlib back out with the updated version of what the user entered. 
Here's my text file:

One of the most adjective characters in fiction is named "Tarzan of the plural-noun." Tarzan was raised by a/an noun and lives in the adjective jungle in the heart of darkest place. He spends most of this time eating plural-noun and swinging from tree to noun. Whenever he gets angry, he beats on his chest and says, "funny-noise !" This is his war cry. Tarzan always dresses in adjective shorts made from the skin of a/an noun and his best friend is a/an adjective chimpanzee names Cheetah. He is supposed to be able to speak to elephants and plural-noun. In the movies, Tarzan is played by person's-name.

The tokens I scan for in the file are these <> (I didn't show them in the text file above but where it says adjective or noun or funny noises its really < adjective > with no space between left arrow adjective and right arrow adjective)  and that's where the users inputs are placed. Everything in my program works except until I print it out. Instead of printing the madlib out in the format above, it just prints it out in one long line. It doesn't have to match the above format, I'd just like it to print a newline after a length of 50 for instance just so it's easier to read.

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class ReadFile 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) //throws Exception
    {
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));
        String line;
        StringBuffer storybuffer=new StringBuffer();

        //Accept lines until next line null
        while((line=br.readLine()) != null)
            storybuffer.append(" "+line);

        //Remove first space
        storybuffer.delete(0, 1);
        String story=storybuffer.toString();
        //Split
        StringTokenizer str=new StringTokenizer(story);
        String word;
        StringBuffer finalstory=new StringBuffer();

        //Store added elements
        Map<String,String> hash=new HashMap<String,String>();

        while(str.hasMoreTokens())
        {
            word=str.nextToken();
            if(word.contains("<"))
            {
                String add="";
                //Element prompt could be more than one word
                if(!word.contains(">"))
                {
                    //Build multi-word prompt
                    String phrase="";
                    do{
                        phrase+=word+" ";
                    }while(!(word=str.nextToken()).contains(">"));
                    word=phrase+word;
                }
                //Account for element placeholder being immediately followed by . or , or whatever.
                if(word.charAt(word.length()-1)!='>')
                    add=word.substring(word.lastIndexOf('>')+1);

                //Store id of element in hash table
                String id=word.substring(0,word.lastIndexOf('>')+1);
                String value;

                if(!hash.containsKey(id))
                {
                    //New element
                    System.out.println("Enter a "+ id);
                    value=s.nextLine()+add;
                    hash.put(id, value);
                }
                //Previously entered element heres the problem for duplicates!
                else
                    value=hash.get(id);
                word=value;
            }
            finalstory.append(word+" ");
//          if(finalstory.length() > 50){
//              finalstory.append("\n");


        }
        System.out.println(finalstory.toString());
        s.close();
    }
}
```

Anyone have any ideas of how to fix this?

Comment: Instead of inserting newlines on the fly, I would take the whole text and pass it in the end through a layout function. This could either be written by yourself or taken from the web. An isolated function is better testable, better reusable, your code is better reusable for instance in a context, where not every character is considered to be of equal width, or where the width of the screen differs (screen size landscape/portrait), or maybe no line break is wanted (text to speech function, for example).

Comment: Okay thanks ill give it a shot!

Comment: In the spirit of this ad-hoc program, write a function, which accepts a StringBuffer (finalstory) and an int (max line length), and and returns a new String with line breaks in place.

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class ReadFile {
 public static void main(String[] args) //throws Exception
  {
   Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));
   String line;
   StringBuffer storybuffer = new StringBuffer();

   //Accept lines until next line null
   while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
    storybuffer.append(" " + line);

   //Remove first space
   storybuffer.delete(0, 1);
   String story = storybuffer.toString();
   //Split
   StringTokenizer str = new StringTokenizer(story);
   String word;
   StringBuffer finalstory = new StringBuffer();

   //Store added elements
   Map < String, String > hash = new HashMap < String, String > ();

   while (str.hasMoreTokens()) {
    word = str.nextToken();
    if (word.contains("<")) {
     String add = "";
     //Element prompt could be more than one word
     if (!word.contains(">")) {
      //Build multi-word prompt
      String phrase = "";
      do {
       phrase += word + " ";
      } while (!(word = str.nextToken()).contains(">"));
       word = phrase + word;
     }
     //Account for element placeholder being immediately followed by . or , or whatever.
     if (word.charAt(word.length() - 1) != '>')
      add = word.substring(word.lastIndexOf('>') + 1);

     //Store id of element in hash table
     String id = word.substring(0, word.lastIndexOf('>') + 1);
     String value;

     if (!hash.containsKey(id)) {
      //New element
      System.out.println("Enter a " + id);
      value = s.nextLine() + add;
      hash.put(id, value);
     }
     //Previously entered element
     else
      value = hash.get(id);
     word = value;
    }
    finalstory.append(word + " ");
    //          if(finalstory.length() > 50){
    //              finalstory.append("\n");


   }
   System.out.println(finalstory.toString());
   s.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you describe what your improvements are, except from ruining the indentation?